# View Controller's Main View is sometimes under status bar, sometimes not

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uistatusbar

I have a View Controller with one main image covering the whole of the view, and a few buttons. When I get to this view through a push segue from the previous controller, the view is shifted downwards below the status bar, showing a black strip where the view is missing (and moving my buttons out of position).

[image: WRONG]

When I show the next screen and dismiss it, the view shifts back to the correct position.

[image: CORRECT]

How can I make sure that the correct distribution of the view (second image) happens every time?

UPDATE:

This is how my storyboard looks:

[image]

Comment: Are you using autolayout? What do your constraints look like?

Comment: No, regular layouts. My image is 0 all around vs. main View, and the buttons are 8 top, 8 left ("volver"), 8 button, centered horizontally ("comenzar")

Comment: If you're using autolayout, you're probably setting your top constraint to be anchored to the "Top Layout Guide" instead of the actual View

Comment: So you're not doing this using a storyboard?

Comment: @Pierce I am. I edited the question to show the constraints.

Comment: did you try  
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {  
    return true  
}  
in appDelegate?

Comment: Select the constraint that says "Img View.top = top" - What does it say in the identity inspector for "Second Item"?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this problem with a simple line of code:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

By the way, this was happening to me on a UIPageViewController and this line of code was included in ViewDidLoad of that VC, not the Content View Controller.